# How to reconstruct F# assembly signature from F# dll

Tags: .net, reflection, f#, signature, f#-3.0

I want to access F# signature data from a compiled F# dll.

I understand that I can get the signature data from the source files using the [FSharp.Compiler.Service](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/) library.  I could not find a way to use that library to produce signature information from a dll without sources.

I see two options, but I think it's possible there may be a simpler solution.  The two options I'm aware of are:

1. Embed the F# source code in the dll and use FSharp.Compiler.Service to extract information from the embedded resource.  I could then make any associations to reflection metadata from correspondence in name.  Unless I did something wrong, FSharp.Compiler.Service can't interpret an .fsi signature file, so it seems that the whole source would need to be embedded for this to work.
2. Reconstruct the F# signature from reflection metadata.  This approach seems necessarily insufficient because some data is not recoverable through reflection (e.g. type aliases).

My question is:

**Is there a better way to access F# signature data and associate it with reflection metadata than I have suggested?**

Another way to look at this question that might make it a little more concrete is, "Given a compiled F# assembly, how can I determine all the type aliases (and referents thereof) that would be available to referencing projects?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is essentially what the [Library documentation part of F# Formatting](http://tpetricek.github.io/FSharp.Formatting/metadata.html) does. It generates documentation from a compiled DLL (together with the XML comments), but the key part is that it loads the metadata about the F# code from the compiled DLL.

The way it works is that it uses the F# Compiler Service to build a project

It uses the F# Compiler Service to load the compiled F# DLL (as if you were referencing it when compiling some code). The F# compiler service then sees all the information about the DLL, including things like aliases (that's what the F# compiler itself sees when you reference a DLL!)

The source code for it is on GitHub - good starting point is the call to `FSharpAssembly.LoadFiles` [here](https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.Formatting/blob/master/src/FSharp.MetadataFormat/Main.fs#L1284), which reads the meta-data that is later processed.

Comment: I figured I just couldn't find it.  Thanks for this and everything else - you've helped me out a lot.

Comment: Where should I look/start if I want to load this model directly from a .fsi (assuming there are no other artifacts available)?

Comment: I don't think you can get it just from FSI file. The method that's used there lets you get it from a compiled F# DLL file (which is what you seem to be looking for - based on the first line of the question :))

Comment: Tomas - You're right that's what I was looking for ... but I got greedy.  Thanks again

Comment: Hehe :-). I think dealing with just FSI files using the compiler service would be harder. It can definitely parse them (and give you an untyped AST), which is a good start, but I think it can only process them into a fully typed AST if it also has the source FS file.